# How to apply the forecast function to each model created in a list R?

Tags: r

```r
setwd("C:\\Users\\Note\\Documents\\Ssl")
n <- dir(pattern = ".csv")
files<- NULL
for (i in n) {  files[[i]] <- read.csv(i,sep = ";",header = T) }
predic<-lapply(files,function(i)auto.arima(i[,1]))


> class(predic)
[1] "list"

>forecast(predic[i],h=15)
Error in x - fits : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(x, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I created the model with auto.arima for each file in a list, how to use the "forecast" function for each file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, the `predic` is called outside the `for` loop.  It could be called inside the `for` loop and there is no `i` index outside the `for` loop env

```
library(dplyr)
files <- vector('list', length(n))
predic <- vector('list', length(n))
forecastOut <- vector('list', length(n))
for (i in seq_along(n)) { 
      files[[i]] <- read.csv(n[i],sep = ";",header = TRUE)
      predic[[i]] <- auto.arima(files[[i]][,1])
      forecastOut[[i]] <- forecast(predic[[i]], n = 15)
      }
```

---

Or if we do this in `lapply`

```
forecastOut <- lapply(n, function(x) {
               dat <- read.csv(x, sep=";", header = TRUE)
               predic <- auto.arima(dat[,1])
               forecast(predic, n = 15)



       })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I realized that the output follows the logic [1], [2], [3] [4], [5], [6], there is a possibility to change the number [1], [2] of spreadsheet by her name from the post?

Comment: @ViniciusSoares  You can set the names of `forecastOut` as `names(forecastOut) <- n; lapply(names(forecastOut), function(nm) write.csv(forecastOut[[nm]], paste0(nm, ".csv")))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it seems like something is wrong is returning me NULL in all names

Comment: @ViniciusSoares  What is the output  of `n`?  if it is the file names, I am assigning that as names of 'forecastOut'